# PuLP Python - How to linearize an inequality involving a variable

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

I am working on a Copper payables problem where the objective function is to maximise the sum of copper payable over a time period, T.

Is it possible to formulate a constraint that compares a variable with/between two constants, dynamically:

i.e.

```
lower_bound, operator_1 (>, >=), variable, operator_2(<, <=) up_bound
```

**Description of the problem**

The total amount of payable tonnes i.e. what the customer will pay for is dependent on the copper content of the sales material.

1. Each customer has a number of payable terms expressed as copper specification operable bounds, as per the below example data:

### Customer data

```
import io
import pandas as pd

customer_payables = """customer, tier, specvalue_1, specoperator_1, specvalue_2, \
specoperator_2, coeff
    'abc', 1, 0, '>=', 20, '<=', 96.0
    'abc', 2, 20, '>', 24, '<=', 96.5 
    'abc', 3, 24, '>', 100, '<=', 96.65
    'def', 1, 0, '>=', 20, '<=', 96.0
    'def', 2, 20, '>=', 22, '<=', 96.66
    'def', 3, 22, '>=', 100', '<=', 97.0
    """

_cust_data = io.StringIO(customer_payables)
cust_df = pd.read_csv(_cust_data, sep=",")
cust_df = cust_df.set_index('customer')
cust_df
```

2. I have a dataframe of available material, in tonnes, with specific copper content in two warehouses with two stockpiles. Note that the quality of this material changes over time:

##Stockpile data

```
stockpile_data_dict = {
    'Warehouse 1':{
        'Stockpile 1': {'cu': 27}, 
        'Stockpile 2': {'cu': 18}
        },
        'Warehouse 2': {
            'Stockpile 1':{'cu': 22}, 
            'Stockpile 2': {'cu': 16}}}
  
stockpile_df = pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v).T for k, v in stockpile_data_dict.items()}, axis=0) 
stockpile_df
```

**Question**
I have created a variable to represent the copper concentration for each warehouse, stockpile. This is kept as a variable as the intention is to model inventory over time, allowing the model a choice of when to sell material in order to maximise the payables:

```
cu_spec_of_sale_material = pulp.LpVariable.dicts(
    'Copper spec of sale material',
    ((warehouse, stockpile)
      for warehouse, stockpile in stockpile_df.index),
      cat='Continuous')
```

How can I create a linear constraint that returns the correct payable coefficient with respect to the copper concentration VALUE of this variable?

In pseudo code terms, it evaluates something like the below:

```
for customer, effective_tier in effective_payable_coefficient:
  if customer_lower_bound_val < cu_spec_sales_material[warehouse, stockpile] < customer_up_bound_val:
    PULP += effective_payable_coefficient[customer, effective_tier] == 1
```

I do not use Pulp very often, so please bear with me.

All help gratefully received, thank you.

Comment: Could you provide a clear concise description of you problem? How would you formulate your constraint, if linearity was not an issue?

Comment: My question is just that - I am unsure of the approach to take here, given the nature of the problem. I have an integer variable representing the cu spec of the material that I need to evaluate against a dataframe of payable terms. Is this possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a linear formulation for the implication:

```
a < x < b => y = 1
```

where a,b are constants, x is a continuous variable and y is a binary variable.

We can write this as:

```
 x ≤ a + M1 ⋅ δ + M1 ⋅ y
 x ≥ b - M2 ⋅ (1-δ) - M2 ⋅ y
 δ,y ∈ {0,1}
 x ∈ [L,U]
 M1 = U-a
 M2 = b-L
```

`δ` is another binary variable, `L`,`U` are lower/upper bounds on `x`, `M1`,`M2` are constants.

Intuition: these constraints implement the implication:

```
 y = 0 =>  x ≤ a or x ≥ b
```

which means that if `a < x < b` we must have `y=1`.

To derive these constraints it is best to move away from your computer and use old-fashioned pen-and-paper.

Comment: This looks exactly what I am looking for, thank you very much. Would it be possible, please, to show what these might represent in the content of the problem? I can see for example, that `x` would represent the copper concentrations, and `a` and `b` represent the customer lower/upper payable bounds? thank you

Comment: `a < x < b => y = 1` is just `if customer_lower_bound_val < cu_spec_sales_material[warehouse, stockpile] < customer_up_bound_val:
    PULP += effective_payable_coefficient[customer, effective_tier] == 1` in simpler terms.